# Deleting branches in git causes gitk to go wild

Tags: git, gitk

I decided to delete a few branches from a (personal project) repository of mine that were merged into `master` after confirming on #git that leftover branches aren't really necessary.

However, gitk's visualisation of my repository's history as a result has been completely screwed up.

Basically something like this:

[image: http://i48.tinypic.com/90r512.png]

With those branches from commits appearing out of nowhere eventually going back into some other commits up ahead. A merge did not occur at all of the points, and I only had around 5 extra branches.

Is this normal? Is there any fix for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried reloading your display? Sometimes gitk gets a bit confused, but quitting and restarting it, or reloading (**File** > **Reload**, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd>) can help it re-draw the history in a more friendly fashion.

**edit**: Now that I see the repository, I can see what's going on.

It looks like you did some development on master, while also working on some side branches. While you were doing this, you merged `master` into those side branches several times. `gitk` displays commits in a list, so it needs a linear ordering of commits. Whenever you have branching history, there are several possible linear orderings you can put that history in. For instance, the following structure:

```
       /-- c -- e --\
a -- b               g -- h
       \-- d -- f --/
```

Could be ordered an any of the following ways:

1. a, b, c, e, d, f, g, h
2. a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h
3. a, b, c, d, f, e, g, h
4. a, b, d, c, e, f, g, h
5. a, b, d, c, f, e, g, h
6. a, b, d, f, c, e, g, h

By default, `gitk` uses a topological ordering, which tries to group together commits on each branch, so you can see a logical progression of commits for each branch, rather than commits of each side of the branch interspersed based on when they happened. So, for instance, it might display them in ordering (1):

```
a -- b -- c -- e ------------ g -- h
       \----------- d -- f --/
```

This ordering works fine if you're just looking at a linear log, and also works fine in `gitk` if you don't merge between the branches very often (as in the example given). But if you do what you did, merging `master` into the topic branches frequently, then this produces the kind of mess that you're seeing; the commits on `master` are shown first, then the commits on the side branches, but the frequent merging of `master` into the side branches become the long connections that pile up and make the history look confusing. (Note that Git doesn't actually store which commits came from which branch, but the way it sorts them it winds up keeping the commits from each branch together, it appears).

The easiest way to deal with this that I know of is just to display commits in `gitk` in chronological order. Open **View** > **Edit view...**, and check the **Strictly sort by date** option. Now you should see your history displayed much more sanely. To launch directly into this view, you can pass the `--date-order` option into `gitk`.

Comment: @a2h In order to help you, we're going to need some more information. Can you show more of the history, including the points where it appears that branching and merging are happening?

Comment: Is there any way I can increase the height of the listing shown at any one time?

Comment: @a2h Is this a public project you have on GitHub? If so, I can probably just pull it and look at it in gitk directly myself.

Comment: @a2h I've edited my answer; hopefully this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for that, it works nicely. Can I ask - does this change of the view get saved into the repository?

Comment: @a2h You can create named views in `gitk`; use `New view...` or `Edit view...`, and check the `Remember this view` checkbox. This will save your view in your `~/.gitk` file (so, it will be saved in your home directory, not in your repository). You can also just pass the `--date-order` option into `gitk` when you launch it to launch directly into a chronological view.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your history looks like, but something to keep in mind: deleting merged branches only deletes the names (refs), not the commits, nor any part of the history.

So tools that visualize history will still show all the branching that has occurred in the past.

Answer (score 0):

A branch is only when you have different heads pointing from root (like in tree), not when you have n-lines going back to main branch (merged ranch is not really different from branch it was merged to). Check `gitk --all` to see all branches you have in repository (as colour labels pointing at head of each branch). And check carefully merge points which gitk shows you, if those have two parents, then they're real merges. `git log --graph` can help you to see that it's not issue of gitk.

Comment: @a2h Are you sure? Have you tried to add `| less` if it isn't run through pager? It shows full repository graph for me back to initial commit.